# the realm is already in a write transaction

Tags: objective-c, transactions, realm

the realm is already in a write transaction.

How can i avoid this error? is there a way to check realm is in write traction? if realm is in write transaction then closed first then do other work. Now after getting this error "the realm is already in a write transaction." then other tasks connected with realm also not working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The rule of thumb for Realm is only one write transaction open on an `RLMRealm` at any given time. You might need to reconsider your logic if you're hitting this error. You shouldn't ever intentionally be trying to open up a second write transaction on a `RLMRealm` that's already open on the same thread. Doing it on separate threads is fine, but the thread the second write transaction is on will be blocked until the first one completes.

If there's something in your implementation that isn't set right, it's also possible that a transaction you've assumed had completed might have had an error and was left open. Like Sebastian said, you can check this with `-[RLMRealm inWriteTransaction]`, but in this case, you should definitely backtrack your code to see why that is happening.

Answer (score 30):

Here is one possible solution that I came across in [this github discussion](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4511#issuecomment-270962198):

```
extension Realm {
    public func safeWrite(_ block: (() throws -> Void)) throws {
        if isInWriteTransaction {
            try block()
        } else {
            try write(block)
        }
    }
}
```

use it like this:

```
try! realm.safeWrite{
    //your write code goes here
}
```

now `safeWrite` will check if there is active transaction and will either start one or just execute the code passed in.

Comment: I have no idea why this isn't in the standard realm library. Its such an obvious inclusion. Good work!

Comment: I may be dense, but what does try block() accomplish?

Comment: Block is the piece of code you pass to the method to execute. So, this is technically checking if a write block is already in progress and if so, then the code you pass in will be executed in that write process, if not, then it will open a new write and execute the code you pass.

Comment: if the code uses an existing write transaction is it guaranteed to complete?,

Comment: @gregm in both cases the snippet executes "block" - the code that you define in the closure. In one case it's called directly and in the other it's passed to "write" which initiates the write transaction inside, executes the "block" and then finishes the transaction. When it comes to executing the "block", fundamentally the flow stays the same in both cases and the "block" will complete as soon as your code completes. Hope that clarifies it a bit and answers your question.

Comment: Good idea....    But, instead of 'try block()', it should throw an error DBError.alreadyInAWriteTransaction. otherwise it defeats the purpose...

Comment: @eharo2 well, throwing that error defeats the purpose of that function altogether as this gets you to the default behaviour which the OP asked to avoid. If you need that behaviour of throwing the error, just use the original realm's "write" function and you'll get the exception if already in write transaction. Otherwise use "safeWrite" to make sure your code is always executed in a transaction, despite if it was opened previously or not.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing some write tasks in the same thread, you can add them to `NSMutableArray`, a then use `addOrUpdateObjectsFromArray`. On the other side, you can check to avoid write conflicts by firing `inWriteTransaction` on realm object.