# Realm is already in a write transaction if I execute two transactions in the same method

Tags: android, database, kotlin, concurrency, realm

I need to eliminate the first records recorded by the realm db if they are more than a certain number, but I get this exception:

`````
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Realm is already in a write transaction in /Users/cm/Realm/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsSharedRealm.cpp line 126
    at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.nativeBeginTransaction(Native Method)
    at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.beginTransaction(OsSharedRealm.java:269)
    at io.realm.BaseRealm.beginTransaction(BaseRealm.java:404)
    at io.realm.Realm.beginTransaction(Realm.java:145)
    at io.realm.Realm.executeTransaction(Realm.java:1491)
    atsavedAddresses(AddressBook.kt:39)````
`````

As you can see below I tried to add `commitTransaction`, to play with `executeTransactionAsync`, and `executeTransaction`, begin transaction etc. But nothing is going to work although I read several so posts and GitHub issues comments , I even found this so [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366182/the-realm-is-already-in-a-write-transaction) but is too abstract to relate to my case

```
init {

    Realm.init(ProActiveApplication.applicationContext())
}


private val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()

val query = realm.where(RecentAddress::class.java).findAll()

fun savedAddresses(name: String, address: String) {
   realm.beginTransaction()
    realm.executeTransactionAsync  {
        val addressToSave = realm.createObject(RecentAddress::class.java)
        addressToSave.name = name
        addressToSave.street = address
        Log.d("ME","-----------------")
        Log.d("ME", " CreateTransaction: ${addressToSave.name} in ${addressToSave.street}")
        Log.d("ME","-----------------")
    }
    realm.commitTransaction()
    realm.close()

    realm.beginTransaction()
    realm.executeTransaction {
        if (query.size > 2) {
            val location = query.get(0)
            Log.d("ME","-----------------")

            Log.d("ME", " This is cancelled: ${query.get(0)}")
            Log.d("ME","-----------------")

            location?.deleteFromRealm()

        } }
```

***EDIT***

As suggested I am going to eliminate `beginTransaction()` and `commitTransaction` also I changed to `executeTransaction` instead of `executeTransactionAsync()

```
    fun savedAddresses(name: String, address: String) {
   // realm.beginTransaction()
    realm.executeTransaction {
        val addressToSave = realm.createObject(RecentAddress::class.java)
        addressToSave.name = name
        addressToSave.street = address
        Log.d("ME", "-----------------")
        Log.d("ME", " CreateTransaction: ${addressToSave.name} in ${addressToSave.street}")
        Log.d("ME", "-----------------")
    }
   // realm.commitTransaction()
    realm.close()

    // realm.beginTransaction()
    realm.executeTransaction {
        if (query.size > 2) {
            val location = query.get(0)
            Log.d("ME", "-----------------")

            Log.d("ME", " This is cancelled: ${query.get(0)}")
            Log.d("ME", "-----------------")

            location?.deleteFromRealm()

        }

    }
```

Now I get that is like Realm is going to cancel the first 0 position, but then is going to add the next record in the 0 position **and not at end** of the list

If I cancel the second block `executeTransaction`  the record are successfully added in sequential order, but remaining the second block, the transaction eliminate row 0 but then insert the second record at the position 0, not at the end of the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to eliminate/remove first two records (if there are) and insert new record at the end of the list. **Try this**

```sh
fun savedAddresses(name: String, address: String) {
   realm.executeTransaction { realm ->
        val addressToSave = realm.createObject(RecentAddress::class.java)
        addressToSave.name = name
        addressToSave.street = address
        //insert the record at the end of the list 
        realm.insert(addressToSave)
    }
    deleteOldRecords()
}

fun deleteOldRecords() {
    realm.executeTransaction { realm -> 
        val recentAddressList = realm.where(RecentAddress::class.java).findAll()
        if(recentAddressList.size > 2){
            for(i in 0..1) {
                recentAddressList.deleteFromRealm(i)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

please correct me if i understood wrong.

Comment: well not exactly, I want to have a consecutive list of items, and since I am showing to the users only the last  n ones, to not make the app db too bigger I want to cut after a certain time(in the example 2, in reality 10) the oldest records

Comment: and now I get `aused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Changing Realm data can only be done from inside a transaction.` at line `recentAddressList.deleteFromRealm(i)`

Comment: I think this should work, I have just tried the same. Let me know

Comment: I have to delete only one record but this is not important, the problem is that as soon as get deleted the transaction is created at [0] the first position, and not at the end

Comment: I think this is due to the fact that the two transactions( insert and delete) are made together, not sandboxed

Comment: solved the problem was in the fact I wanted to save the record as last, and this is not easy, so I reverted the list in the adapter and now works well

Answer (score 2):

If you using `executeTransaction` you don't need to write manually `beginTransaction()` and `commitTransaction()` it do it all for you.
 so basically you `beginTransaction()` and then start `executeTransaction` block and you get transaction inside transaction, this why the crash, also you can do all this code in one transaction.

Comment: does not work what you suggest, because if I remove what you say. Realm is going to cancel the Array 0, but then is going to insert the next record in the array zero position and not at end of the Realm list, this is why I am desperately trying to sandbox them in different transactions

Comment: what you mean Realm is going to cancel the Array 0?

Comment: Please @Pavel Poley see my edit. above  I mean that is like after that Realm cancel the row zero of the RealmObject, then insert the next record in this zero position, and not in the `n` sequential position I expect( at the end of the list)